# Material button animation does not come in HTML Web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I tried to make my website buttons to Material Design with its animation as [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqajNX) but only button comes as the result and no animation! I guess JavaScript is not being detected.
Im new to web designing! someone please help me out!
Please check below whether i made any mistake.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/files/favicon+1.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/files/favicon192.png" sizes="196x196" type="image/png" />
    <title>Material Button</title>
    <style>
      html {
        background: salmon;
      }
      
      * {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }
      
      .wrap {
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .button {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0.3em;
        padding: 1.2em 5em;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s;
        -o-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border: none;
        
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .button:hover {
        box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
      
      .green {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .red {
        background-color: #F44336;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .blue {
        background-color: #03A9F4;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .ripple {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 100%;
        transform: scale(0.2);
        opacity:0;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-animation: ripple .75s ease-out;
        -moz-animation: ripple .75s ease-out;
        animation: ripple .75s ease-out;
      }
      
      @-webkit-keyframes ripple {
        from {
          opacity:1;
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      
      @-moz-keyframes ripple {
        from {
          opacity:1;
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      
      @keyframes ripple {
        from {
          opacity:1;
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      
      
    </style>
    <script language="javascript">

 $('.button').mousedown(function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var ripple = target.querySelector('.ripple');
    $(ripple).remove();
    ripple = document.createElement('span');
    ripple.className = 'ripple';
    ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = Math.max(rect.width, rect.height) + 'px';
    target.appendChild(ripple);
    var top = e.pageY - rect.top - ripple.offsetHeight / 2 -  document.body.scrollTop;
    var left = e.pageX - rect.left - ripple.offsetWidth / 2 - document.body.scrollLeft;
    ripple.style.top = top + 'px';
    ripple.style.left = left + 'px';
    return false;
});

</script>
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1>Material Design Button</h1>
      <a class="button blue" href="#">Hover Me</a>
      <a class="button red" href="#">Click Me</a>
      <a class="button green" href="#">Love Me</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with this:

Jquery javascript isn't included. You could let google host it for you or put it in your project and reference it. It wasn't so much that javascript wasn't "being detected" but that jquery didn't yet exist on the page. When clicking on the settings button in the link you posted and then clicking on the javascript tab, you can see where that example got jquery.

Aside from that, the button event was being bound before the document was ready.

Here's an example with both of those in place - the script tag is added above the button event and the button event code is wrapped in $(function(){ ... });, shorthand for jQuery's document ready function. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/files/favicon+1.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/files/favicon192.png" sizes="196x196" type="image/png" />
    <title>Material Button</title>
    <style>
      html {
        background: salmon;
      }
      
      * {
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      }
      
      .wrap {
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .button {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0.3em;
        padding: 1.2em 5em;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s;
        -ms-transition: 0.3s;
        -o-transition: 0.3s;
        transition: 0.3s;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        border: none;
        
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .button:hover {
        box-shadow: 1px 6px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }
      
      .green {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .red {
        background-color: #F44336;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .blue {
        background-color: #03A9F4;
        color: white;
      }
      
      .ripple {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        border-radius: 100%;
        transform: scale(0.2);
        opacity:0;
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-animation: ripple .75s ease-out;
        -moz-animation: ripple .75s ease-out;
        animation: ripple .75s ease-out;
      }
      
      @-webkit-keyframes ripple {
        from {
          opacity:1;
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      
      @-moz-keyframes ripple {
        from {
          opacity:1;
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      
      @keyframes ripple {
        from {
          opacity:1;
        }
        to {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }
      
      
    </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
$(function(){
 $('.button').mousedown(function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var ripple = target.querySelector('.ripple');
    $(ripple).remove();
    ripple = document.createElement('span');
    ripple.className = 'ripple';
    ripple.style.height = ripple.style.width = Math.max(rect.width, rect.height) + 'px';
    target.appendChild(ripple);
    var top = e.pageY - rect.top - ripple.offsetHeight / 2 -  document.body.scrollTop;
    var left = e.pageX - rect.left - ripple.offsetWidth / 2 - document.body.scrollLeft;
    ripple.style.top = top + 'px';
    ripple.style.left = left + 'px';
    return false;
});
});

</script>
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h1>Material Design Button</h1>
      <a class="button blue" href="#">Hover Me</a>
      <a class="button red" href="#">Click Me</a>
      <a class="button green" href="#">Love Me</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```